# Bypass DNS with .URL file

Tags: facebook, url, powershell, dns

So this may be on here as another question, feel free to move this to Server Fault if it's not appropriate for SO. Anyway here's the jist of it.

I am in an environment where Internet access is restricted by DNS policy.
The website for this project is www.facebook.com.
We have a marketing department that wants access to this site for social media marketing or whatever, and I have been tasked with somehow granting them access without changing the DNS policy.

Initially I wrote a couple powershell scripts to give the user a static IP address and flush their DNS, then assign 8.8.8.8 (Google) dNS instead of our own. Unfortunately, the Address assigning, and potential to break/manipulate the script was too much of a risk. We want to take the "work" out of the user's hands.

The next idea was to have a "Favorites" icon (.URL file) where we have a script that pulls the IP address from www.facebook.com and replaces the URL in the file. Here's the script.

```
$outfile = "\\fhnsrv01\home\user\Documentation\Projects\Hussein\DNSScript\facebook.url"
$ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
$ips = $($ping.Send("www.facebook.com").Address).IPAddressToString

Write-Host $ips
GC $outfile| Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})", $ips}
```

Here's the URL file.

```
[DEFAULT]
BASEURL=http://www.facebook.com/
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,2
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://10.159.19.11/
IDList=
IconFile=http://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico
IconIndex=1
```

This seems to work, the IP for Facebook gets updated every day so I need to run this every day, but for some reason this won't resolve. I got it to work a couple times...but it was end of day and can't exactly recall the steps I took.

In essence, I should be able to double click the .URL file and it should take me to the IP of Facebook, essentially bypassing the DNS resolution in favor of a direct connection.

Now when I click the .URL file it just times out. Can't reach the site.

I've tried flushing my DNS and register which doesn't seem to help any.

**Questions**

Where can I look for clues on how to get this to work?

Am I missing a key component in getting this to work?

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is it any different if you use URL=http://...? I am wondering if it is the browser that is dropping it because ssl cert would not be for the ip...

Comment: hmm good question let me try.